# Couldn't create DrawBox plugin with opengeo client sdk

Tags: geoext, boundless-suite

I followed the official tutorial explaining how to create personal plugin with openGeo client sdk but unfortunately I couldn't perform that task.
In the beggining, I "copy/ past" the code as it mentioned in the tutorial but my browser told me that gxp is not defined after that I make changes as follows:

```
/**
*
* @require plugins/Tool.js
*/

/** api: (extends)
*  plugins/Tool.js
*/

Ext.namespace("gxp.plugins");
//Ext.ns("carta.plugins");

gxp.plugins.DrawBox = Ext.extend(gxp.plugins.Tool, {
ptype: "gxp_drawbox",
addActions: function(){
    return gxp.plugins.DrawBox.superclass.addActions.apply(this, [{
        text: "Draw box"
    }]);
}
});

Ext.preg(gxp.plugins.DrawBox.prototype.ptype, gxp.plugins.DrawBox);
```

Then, when I examine the code with chrome I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined ext-base.js:7
Ext.apply.extend ext-base.js:7
(anonymous function)
```

Do you have any hints about resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK is not very forgiving when parsing the `@require` directives. Make sure that each `@require` line starts with blank-star-blank, and not just with star-blank.

Comment: oh great !!!
I should start with blank-start-blank 
thank you the problem is resolved